# Using Visual Studio to search and display a piece of source code

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

First off, I would like to point out I'm new to Visual Studio and have set myself a project of building a custom web browser for a game I play.

Is there a way for my custom browser to search the source code of the site and display a piece of it?

Example. search for "hpcurrent=15" and display "15"

I'm sorry if this is basic but I'm very new to VS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any information you could point me to? I dont really know where to start and ive been searching all day

Comment: It would seriously help if you told us what language you're using...

Comment: Oh sorry. From what I see and from other tutorials it just says vs.

Comment: C, C#, C++, VB, PHP, Java, etc...? VS is the editor, not the language.

Comment: Ah I then its vb. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use VB often (I find C# a lot easier to work with), but something like this should work (not tested):

```
Dim Input As String = New WebClient().DownloadString("http://example.com")
Dim Match As Match = Regex.Match(Input, "hpcurrent=(\d+)")
If Match.Success Then
    MessageBox.Show(Match.Groups(1).Value)
End If
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm having a problem with "IF" It says "Statement cannot appear outside of a method body/multiline lambda. Have I placed it wrong.

Comment: Iv'e played with it a bit and it all goes in nicely. The problem I have now is the value cannot be null. The "(Input," is used before being assigned a value. My guess would be the "hpcurrent" cannot be found on the homepage but only when I sign in. I get the error before I can sign in.

Comment: Have you actually written the code to put the webpage's source code into the `Input` variable yet?

Comment: I would say, no. I hope it's not too much bother for you to tell me how. If it is, could you suggest some reading material. Thanks.

Comment: @viper14lk I thought you said you'd been making a custom web browser? I've edited my answer (which I got straight from [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=vba+get+source+code+from+website&oq=vb+get+source&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5608j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=122&espv=210&q=vb.net+get+source+code+from+website&safe=off))

Comment: I have. I can browse the internet but that's as far as I've gotten. I started today. Been fun. Thanks for the code. Ill try.